# Conditionally setting the required parameters in Google DialogFlow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am working on a chatbot that is used to create leave requests. I have created an intent called "create_leave" and associated it with different system entities such as sys.date, sys.date-period to extract the dates from the text. The user can enter "I need leave from March 23 to march 25" or "I need leave on March 28". The problem is even though the user enters "I need leave on March 28", It still asks for the duration which is like "March 23 to 25".. So the solution should be either one of these are entered, the chatbot should not ask the duration again. So How do i conditionally set this?.. Please help. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you update the question to include a screen shot of the intent as you've written it so far, including the sample phrases and the parameters?

Comment: @Prisoner op can't insert screenshot, only link to one. Code should never be screenshots, either.

Comment: The "code" in question in this case is the Intent screen from Dialogflow, which is a web form.

Comment: Hi, Here are some of the Training phrases I have included for the intent "create_leave".  1. "I need leave on 23rd march" 2. "I'm going for my friends marriage. So create leave request from casual leaves from april 21 to april 25" 3. "I'm going for my friends marriage. So create leave request from casual leaves from april 21 to april 25"

Comment: @Vijay - having the screen shot is important since it shows us which parts of the training phrase belong to which parameter. If you can take a screen shot and post it publicly somewhere and link to it, it will help.